# Discord Python - How to make the BOT say all the messages of a channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Do anyone please know how to make the BOT say all the messages of a channel?

Comment: What do you mean?  Like the bot deletes messages that people send and then reposts them?

Comment: No but just make him say the content of every messages of a channel

Comment: Where would the bot repeat those messages to?

Comment: To the ctx.message.channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event that echoes the contents of messages sent by other people in the channel.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

channel_ids = ("1234", "5678")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if message.channel.id in channel_ids:
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, message.content)
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to have a command, that can be run everywhere, that automatically sends all the message contents of a specific channel

Comment: Do you know how I can do this ?

Comment: You could use [`logs_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from) to get the messages from the channel.  You have to specify a number of messages to fetch though, you can't just get all of them (you can specify a very high number though)

Comment: Oh ok, then do I say `bot.say(message.content)` ?

Comment: How do you end it ?